# Keeping commits back for later squashing

Tags: git

I want to contribute to a Git repo. Doing so involves

- coding (e.g. adding features) and
- adding documentation for
  undocumented functions (which goes also in the code files, to be later
  processed by a documentation generator like Javadoc).

To make the owners live easier, i want to squash the documentation related commits.
I've read how to squash the latest commits together, but in my case the documentation related commits will be scattered among others, so especially not the last *n* commits.

Is there an easy way to keep the documentation related commits back from beeing pushed so i can squash them later (e.g. by considering the commit message)? Or should i open a new branch where i just work on the documentation and squash whenever it is convinient, while doing the coding on the master branch?

**Edit:**

Thanks for your answers. There was some lack of knowledge about branching on my side. Indeed as suggested by you simple branching for working on documentation solved my "problem".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a branch anyways, no matter what. Inside that branch, you’re free to do what you want. For later squashing, you should make yourself familiar with the `git rebase` command, specifically the `-i` option. The workflow would be something along the lines of:

1. Clone the repository, make your own branch off the master branch (let’s call it `branch`) and use that from now on
2. Repeat until done:

   1. Work on your changes, make commits as often as sensible
   2. Whenever you need code from upstream, switch to `master`, run `git pull --ff` (this should never fail, as you don’t do changes to master). switch back to `branch` and run `git rebase master`.
3. When done, run step 2.2 one more time, and then run `git rebase -i master` and model your commits to your liking.

`git rebase -i` will allow you to edit, reorder and squash individual commits, you can thus put all your docs changes into one commit by first reordering and then squashing them.

---

N.B.: If I were upstream, I would prefer to have the documentation changes as closely coupled to the code changes as possible, so that the documentation is always up-to-date with the code of the specific commit. Thus, it might make sense to *not* squash all documentation commits together, but to squash them into the corresponding code changing commits.

---

Also, you should seek contact with upstream, what they prefer for commits. Different people have (very) different opinions on that.

Answer (score 2):

Why will your commits be scattered? Work on a branch, and either don't pull until you are done (commit, commit, commit, squash, pull) or use pull -rebase until you are ready to squash and push.